# When I am trying to run following code i am getting error message oledb exception

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Here is my code which is associated with a button. Basically i want to recalculate the value of **"MI"** and update in all the database automatically. When run this code i get

> error message of unhandled oledb exception with additional
>   information: too many fields defined

. Can any body help me to locate whats wrong with it.

```
    CustomersBindingSource.MoveFirst()
    Dim b As Integer
    b = CustomersBindingSource.Count
    Dim n As Integer
    n = 0
    While n <= b
        Button1.PerformClick()
        n = n + 1
        CustomersBindingSource.MoveNext()
    End While

    Form7.Show()
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail with regards to what _CustomersBindingSource_ is?

Comment: Where have you used oledb objects in this code.?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 While n <= b 
 if n = b then
    Button1.PerformClick()
    n = n + 1
 else
    n = n + 1
    CustomersBindingSource.MoveNext()
 end if
End While
```

It might be possible that it is an index out of range error when trying to run CustomersBindingSource.MoveNext()